# Adding class to match() results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code that will search for text on a page and filter the results:

```js
$('#searchbox').on('input', function() {
  var searchWord = $('#searchbox').val().toUpperCase();
  $('.searchParent').each(function() {
    var par = $(this);
    if ($(this).find('.searchMe').text().toUpperCase().match(searchWord) || searchWord == '') {
      $(par).fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(par).fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="searchbox">

<div class="searchParent">
  <span class="searchMe">A</span>
  <span class="searchMe">1</span>
</div>
<div class="searchParent">
  <span class="searchMe">B</span>
  <span class="searchMe">2</span>
</div>
<div class="searchParent">
  <span class="searchMe">C</span>
  <span class="searchMe">3</span>
</div>
```

How can I go about adding a class to the `.searchMe` container where the text was found?

I've tried using `parent()`, but since the results of `match()` return the string itself, and not the element that contains it, that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead.

```js
$('#searchbox').on('input', function() {
  var searchWord = $('#searchbox').val().toUpperCase();
  $('.searchParent').each(function() {
    var par = $(this);
    $(this).find('.searchMe').removeClass('found').filter(function(){
      return searchWord != '' && $(this).text().toUpperCase().match(searchWord);
    }).addClass('found');
  });
});
```

```css
.found{color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="searchbox">

<div class="searchParent">
  <span class="searchMe">A</span>
  <span class="searchMe">1</span>
</div>
<div class="searchParent">
  <span class="searchMe">B</span>
  <span class="searchMe">2</span>
</div>
<div class="searchParent">
  <span class="searchMe">C</span>
  <span class="searchMe">3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('#searchbox').on('input', function() {
  var searchWord = $('#searchbox').val().toUpperCase();
  $('.searchParent').each(function() {
    var par = $(this);
    if ($(this).find('.searchMe').text().toUpperCase().match(searchWord) || searchWord == '') {
      $(par).fadeIn();
      $(this).find('.searchMe').addClass('found');
      if(searchWord == '') {
        $(this).find('.searchMe').removeClass('found');
      }
    } else {
      $(par).fadeOut();
      console.log(2)
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.found{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="searchbox">

<div class="searchParent">
  <span class="searchMe">A</span>
  <span class="searchMe">1</span>
</div>
<div class="searchParent">
  <span class="searchMe">B</span>
  <span class="searchMe">2</span>
</div>
<div class="searchParent">
  <span class="searchMe">2</span>
  <span class="searchMe">3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close, but it highlights both "A" and "1" when I search for just "A"